# MySQL Statement Fails When Checkboxes Are Not Checked

Tags: mysql, html, perl, forms, web

I have a web form that includes checkboxes.

When the form is submitted, a MySQL statement is generated that will insert the data from the form into a database table.

If any of the checkboxes are not checked, the MySQL will fail.  If I check them all, then it works.

I realize this is because the form processor (a Perl program) doesn't "see" the checkboxes if they are not checked, and thus the MySQL statement is not valid, as it is trying to submit non-existent data.

The work-around I use is to do a statement like this before creating the MySQL statement:

```
if (!defined $input{'checkbox_name'}) {$input{'checkbox_name'} = "";}
```

That works, but I assume there's a better way to do all of this.

Comment: Explain concretely and in detail what the failure is. (Hint: set [DBI_TRACE](http://p3rl.org/DBI#DBI_TRACE) to see the SQL statements). Show the relevant HTML and Perl source code that exhibits the problem so it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much what you have to do to assert that some variable has a value, although Perl has some syntax to make this more concise:

```
$input{'checkbox-name'} //= '';
```

See [`perlop`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlop#C-style_Logical_Defined-Or).

In Perl versions earlier than 5.10, before the `//` and `//=` operators were introduced,

```
$input{'checkbox-name'} ||= '';
```

is mostly equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I wasn't aware of that syntax you posted.  I'll try using that.  At least it's a little less code!